# Codeigniter reference MY_Controller in form helper

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

If I have a callback function within MY_Controller that processes a form :

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    function login(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true){
            //do something
        }
    }

}
```

How should I go about referencing it with a form helper in my view?

```
echo form_open('?/login');
```

The reasoning behind this is that we have a login form within a header template that doesn't have a corresponding controller, it's being loaded before each view.  We are hiding the login form with JS if session data is set, so it seems most logical to place the callback within MY_Controller, I'm just unsure how to access it with the form helper class.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `form_open('MY_Controller/login');`

Comment: what is your `default_controller` name ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are placing `login()` inside of `MY_Controller` and extending `CI_Controller`, every controller gains that method. Then, you could use `$this->router->fetch_class();` to get the name of the current controller, and append it before `/login`.

Ex.

```
var $controller = $this->router->fetch_class();
echo form_open($controller.'/login');
```

Comment: Very nice, I like this since using MY_Controller is not good restful uri design to say the least.  This way, the login function is always in context, literally speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Add two library-

```
 $this->load->helper('form');
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

in your controller constructor and add this

```
echo form_open('MY_Controller/login');
```

in view

Answer (score 0):

You can access `login()` function of `MY_Controller` like

```
form_open('default_controller_name/login');
```

if there is no  `login()` function in your `default_controller`